# A graph theory question regarding discharging method

Tags: graph-theory

I've run into an exercise while studying Modern Graph Theory by Bela Bollobas. I'm trying to solve it. I probably need to use discharging method. However, I couldn't simply grasp the idea of applying it. Can anybody help please? Thanks in advance.

Let G be a maximal planar graph of order at least 25 and minimal degree 5. Call a vertex a major vertex if its degree is at least 7  otherwise" call it minor. Then G contains one of the following:

1. a minor vertex with 3 consecutive neighbours of degree 5,
2. a vertex of degree 5 with minor neighbours only)
3. a major vertex with at most one neighbour of degree at least 6.

Comment: maximal with respect to what relation? What is an order?

Comment: Order is the number of vertices of the graph. And a maximal planar graph is  simple planar graph that contains largest possible number of edges. I.e if you connect any pair of nonadjacent vertices, the resulting graph will be nonplanar.

Comment: Can you define consecutive neighbors?

Comment: Two vertices that are connected by an edge are called consecutive vertices. Consecutive neighbours are that neighbours of a vertex that are connected by an edge.

Comment: Two vertices that are connected by an edge are called **adjacent vertices** or neighbors to my knowledge. You should not define **consecutive neighbors** using the word neighbors. I'll try to help you, is this true: consecutive neighbors are two vertices with common adjacent vertex?

Comment: Yes, the definition you gave is more suitable. True. You are right.